# Como Reaccionar individualmente a varios elementos con una misma clase

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

[image: PRIMERA VISTA DE LOS PRODUCTOS]
**SE SUPONE QUE SUS DESCRIPCIONES SE DEBEN OCULTAR NI BIEN TERMINA DE CARGAR LA PAGINA**

[image: HACIENDO HOVER EN PRODUCTOS]
**SE SUPONE QUE AL HACER HOVER EN LOS PRODUCTOS DEBERIA DE MOSTRARSE SU DESCRIPCION**

**Además la descripción se muestra con una animación particular **

**y también se va con una animación particular **

*lo cual solo pasa cuando selección por ID y solo ocurre en el primer elemento *

Estuve investigando tooooooooodo, el día, probe seleccionar por ID por Clase, usar QuerySelectors,
Buscar la forma de hacerlo cíclicamente, pero aún no consigo lo deseado que es esto:

Carga la página, y ningún producto tiene descripción, lo cual entiendo que equivale a que la misma esta con la propiedad visibility : hidden;
Okey, luego, cuando se pasa el mouse por alguno de los productos, entonces:

1.- aparece la descripción con su respectiva animación.
2.- se cambia la propiedad de esa descripción a visibility: visible; (ya que la característica de la animación de salida oculta el elemento sin necesidad de esta propiedad)

por ultimo: cuando se sale afuera del elemento: ocurre la animación de salida que hace que la descripcion desaparezca sutilmente..

El punto es que si la propiedad visibility no se cambia a "visible" sacar el hover del producto, la descripción se desaparece bruscamente y no sutilmente, por eso es necesario que se mantenga como visible después de la primera interacción, y solo después de la primera. ☺♥

Tremendo caos todo esto, pero bueno, no encuentro solución, y es algo tan simple lo que necesito, dios santo

```js
const producto = document.querySelectorAll(".productos");
const descripciones = document.querySelectorAll(".descripcion");

// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE ESTA EN  EL PRODUCTO :
producto.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
    descripciones.classList.add("text-in")    
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-out")
});

// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE SE VA DEL PRODUCTO :
producto.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{
    descripciones.classList.add("text-out")
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-in")    
});

// OCULTAR DESCRIPCIONES CUANDO CARGA LA PAGINA.
const numeroDeProductos = descripciones.length;
function ocultar() {for (var i = 0; i < numeroDeProductos; i++) {descripciones[i].classList.add("ocultar");}}
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {ocultar();});
</script>

<!-- SCRIPT OPCION 2 -->
<script>
const producto = document.querySelectorAll(".productos");
const descripciones = document.querySelectorAll(".descripcion");

// OCULTAR DESCRIPCIONES CUANDO CARGA LA PAGINA.
const numeroDeProductos = descripciones.length;
function ocultar() {for (var i = 0; i < numeroDeProductos; i++) {descripciones[i].classList.add("ocultar");}}
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {ocultar();});


// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE SE VA DEL PRODUCTO :
function mouseArriba() {
    descripciones.classList.add("text-in");    
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-out");
}// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE ESTA EN  EL PRODUCTO :

function mouseAfuera() {
    descripciones.classList.add("text-in")    
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-out")
}
descripciones.forEach(element => {element.addEventListener("mouseover",mouseArriba)});
descripciones.forEach(element => {element.addEventListener("mouseout",mouseAfuera)});
```

```css
.contenedorGrupal{
padding-top: 30px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap ;
justify-content: center;
}

.productos{
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

.productos:hover{
    background-color: rgba(236, 97, 139, 0.432);
    transition: 2s;
    transform: scale(1.2);    
    cursor: pointer;
}


.descripcion {    
    padding: 5px 35px;    
    white-space: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;    
}
.ocultar{visibility: hidden;}

.imgProducto{width: 150px;}

/*. aparece texto */

.text-in {animation: text-in 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;}
@keyframes text-in {
0% {
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
    
}
100% {
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible; 
}
}


/*. desaparece texto */
.text-out {animation: text-out 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.980, 0.335) both;}
@keyframes text-out {
0% {
    filter: blur(0.01); 
}
100% {
    filter: blur(12px) opacity(0%);
    visibility: visible; 
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="CONTENEDOR_TOTAL">
        <div class="contenedorGrupal">
            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="/recursos/producto ejemplo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="/recursos/producto ejemplo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="/recursos/producto ejemplo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios errores, el más importantes es este:

```
const producto = document.querySelectorAll(".productos");

// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE ESTA EN  EL PRODUCTO :
producto.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
    descripciones.classList.add("text-in")    
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-out")
});
```

querySelectorAll devuelve una lista, por lo que tienes que realizar un foreach, algo así:

```
// REACCIONAR CUANDO EL MOUSE ESTA EN  EL PRODUCTO :
producto.forEach( function(){
 this.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
    descripciones.classList.add("text-in")    
    descripciones.classList.remove("text-out")
});
});
```

Después dentro del foreach vas agregando el listener del evento a cada producto. Pero esto para mi es un lio inecesario, con colocar los eventos dentro de la etiqueta html te ahorras mil dolores de cabeza

```
<article class="productos" onmouseover="mouseInOut(this)" onmouseout="mouseInOut(this)">
```

```js
function mouseInOut(el){
  const descripciones = el.querySelector(".descripcion");
  descripciones.classList.toggle("text-in");
  descripciones.classList.toggle("text-out");
}
```

```css
.contenedorGrupal{
padding-top: 30px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap ;
justify-content: center;
}

.productos{
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

.productos:hover{
    background-color: rgba(236, 97, 139, 0.432);
    transition: 2s;
    transform: scale(1.2);    
    cursor: pointer;
}


.descripcion {    
    padding: 5px 35px;    
    white-space: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;    
}
.ocultar{visibility: hidden;}

.imgProducto{width: 150px;}

/*. aparece texto */

.text-in {animation: text-in 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;}
@keyframes text-in {
0% {
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
    
}
100% {
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible; 
}
}


/*. desaparece texto */
.text-out {animation: text-out 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.980, 0.335) both;}
@keyframes text-out {
0% {
    filter: blur(0.01); 
}
100% {
    filter: blur(12px) opacity(0%);
    visibility: visible; 
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="CONTENEDOR_TOTAL">
        <div class="contenedorGrupal">
            <article class="productos" onmouseover="mouseInOut(this)" onmouseout="mouseInOut(this)">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos" onmouseover="mouseInOut(this)" onmouseout="mouseInOut(this)">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos" onmouseover="mouseInOut(this)" onmouseout="mouseInOut(this)">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>
        </div>
</section>
```

***UPDATE: SOLUCIÓN SOLO CON CSS***

Después de analizar bien lo que querías, la verdad es que no necesitas javascript ni animaciones. Solo con CSS usando hover y transiciones se puede lograr que creo que buscas

```css
.contenedorGrupal{
padding-top: 30px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap ;
justify-content: center;
}

.productos{
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
 transition: 2s;
}

.productos:hover{
    background-color: rgba(236, 97, 139, 0.432);
   
    transform: scale(1.2);    
    cursor: pointer;
}


.descripcion {    
    padding: 5px 35px;    
    white-space: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center; 
    transition: 2s;
     filter: blur(12px);
      opacity: 0;
    
}

.productos:hover .descripcion{
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;

}
.ocultar{visibility: hidden;}

.imgProducto{width: 150px;}
```

```html
<section class="CONTENEDOR_TOTAL">
        <div class="contenedorGrupal">
            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>

            <article class="productos">
                <img class="imgProducto" src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stack_Overflow_Logo.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="descripcion text-out">Breve descripcion del producto</h4>
            </article>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Por favor @Yussef , una maravilla tus dos respuestas funcionan a la perfeccion, la verdad es que me lei tantas cosas y ninguna solucionaba mis problemas, que no sabia que hacer... Me recomendas algun tipo de lectura para poder comprender tus conocimientos y tu mirada, porque sinceramente si lo tubiera que haber resuelto solo, quizas no hubiese podido, te debo el cielo ♥

Comment: Mira que me hiciste sonrojar. Lamentablemente no se me ocurre ningún recurso para recomendar. Pero cualquier problema que tenga lo publicas aquí y te ayudaremos. Mucha suerte en tu proyecto